# Powershell Script to build TFS Work Items 400: Bad Request

Tags: powershell, tfs, powershell-3.0, tfs-2015

I've been working on building a script that will grab a bunch of data from my Database then use that data to build work items. I have debugged it down to it can make 59/60 available entries. One entry however has been bombing out and I have no idea why. I originally thought it was PowerShell or TFS just bouncing my requests so I dropped the number of items to create down to 3 and it still breaks at the same entry.

```
Exception calling "Save" with "0" argument(s): "The request was rejected by the server.
FullyQualifiedErrorId : TeamFoundationServerInvalidRequestException
```

In the past I've been able to debug any save errors by using the .validate on my work item store. What could be causing this to bomb out? TFS doesn't see any problems with the data that I'm putting into the work item or else it should show up in the validate call.

Comment: It's wired that the work item can be validated but can't be saved. Could you try to manually create a work item with the problem data to see whether you can save it?

Comment: Where is the the most awkward part. So trying to run it with less data it broke. But when i made the query pull a larger number of items it worked. I know its kind of fragile when working with TFS this way but i guess it works now? I'd still like to know why it would break like that but I don't know what to look at specifically

Comment: Do you mean your script is working now? How many data do you extract when you get a successful result? It's hard to find the root cause unless we can find the problem data which can't create work item.

Comment: I am using this script to query into the Maximo Ticket Table. When i limit it to say 60 records or even 3 records it didnt work. When i opened it up to 80+ it was no longer an issue. So i do not even know if it was a data issue or not.